# How to render a stacked-bar chart and grouped-bar chart in vega-lite?

Tags: bar-chart, vega-lite, stacked-chart

I've created the following grouped bar chart, but now I want to combine the "Earned Income" and "Funding Income" datapoints into a single stacked-bar.

The end result should have 2 bars for each group: 1 bar combining "Earned Income" and "Funding Income" stacked on eachother, and a second bar showing "Expenses" by itself.

I've sort of gotten there using layers.. but the "Expenses" bar is overlayed on top of the others..

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Year": 2022, "Group": "Funding Income", "Value": 7000},
      {"Year": 2022, "Group": "Earned Income", "Value": 3000},
      {"Year": 2022, "Group": "Expenses", "Value": 8000},
      {"Year": 2021, "Group": "Funding Income", "Value": 6000},
      {"Year": 2021, "Group": "Earned Income", "Value": 3000},
      {"Year": 2021, "Group": "Expenses", "Value": 5000}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.Group == 'Funding Income' || datum.Group == 'Earned Income'"}],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Year", "type": "ordinal"},
        "y": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative"},
       //"xOffset": {"field": "Group"},
        "color": {"field": "Group"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "bar",
            "transform": [{"filter": "datum.Group == 'Expenses'"}],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Year"},
        "y": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "xOffset": {"field": "Group"},
        "color": {"field": "Group"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Open in Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAJpwkAJzQAmAAzXrSgOIW2DHGhAAxBrOU1ZMgACAElZKDYEOEUQADUdPTQAdltUgF8FU3MrVDsHZ1d3TwBRS1k4ZVDwyOileN1o1ABmVNsMrMsbe0cQFzcPdGKADxw4WQh9GPrE1AAOVvaQM07c+wBGAv7PHz8A4LCIqKmExoA2Bcyl7K7rDd7CgZBSi3LKg5rjhrQW9MvlnLydz6RUGIzGEwMdROaDECwAuhkQIIkABPOA5YwgZAWADWniYnSUmAsSHGADM2BYEEZQGSaIJMOjPKpMAwEJRgTgggBeblBADkO38gSqhzg-KCAB9JUEWWyOQ8eXz+c9XqKavyQGk4UoxhFhWQ0KAhkaQHS4IJlJ5-jFMCjRp5KcKdFqlCjTebLZ5prUQHaHegAI4MUmYOhqGikV0gCKCSkemgWq3oTlatKLbF49AEqxEknkynU1CYukMpnoOXszlKgXDUbjfSa7W66oG00mzRmxNe9A2xHuzue5NxaFE+2NEDB0PhsNRxFDADyZLJE0wCaTnlTiNj8cH3eHW-TCKAA)

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

[image]

If so, I would augment your source data.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Year": 2022, "Group": "Funding Income", "Value": 7000, "Type": "a"},
      {"Year": 2022, "Group": "Earned Income", "Value": 3000, "Type": "a"},
      {"Year": 2022, "Group": "Expenses", "Value": 8000, "Type": "b"},
      {"Year": 2021, "Group": "Funding Income", "Value": 6000, "Type": "a"},
      {"Year": 2021, "Group": "Earned Income", "Value": 3000, "Type": "a"},
      {"Year": 2021, "Group": "Expenses", "Value": 5000, "Type": "b"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Year"},
    "y": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "xOffset": {"field": "Type"},
    "color": {"field": "Group"}
  }
}
```