Problems with displaying 3 field Column in 1 Chart :(
Problems with displaying the first field as 1 column, while the other 2 fields are overlapped, placed next to the first field, divided by month to easily view monthly data totals.
    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": { "name": "dataset" },
  
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "datum.Date",
      "as": "Date"
    }
  ],
  
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "timeUnit": "month",
      "title": "Month",
      "axis": {"format": "%b"},
      "scale": {"padding": 0.3}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "green", "xOffset": -10},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "PlusQuatation", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "orange", "xOffset": 10},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Expected", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "blue", "xOffset": -10},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Actual", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Values"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "title": "Actual, Expected, and PlusQuatation over Time",
  "config": {
    "axis": {"titleFontSize": 12, "labelFontSize": 10},
    "legend": {"orient": "bottom", "labelFontSize": 10}
  },
  "width": 800
}

enter image description here
We want the result to be similar to the attached picture, but let the orange color become another column bar near the other 2 fields.
and I just want the graphs that are stacked to be overlapping instead of the other single bars being the same as before
enter image description here
enter image description here

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191680/how-to-render-a-stacked-bar-chart-and-grouped-bar-chart-in-vega-lite

It's almost done, but I just want the graphs that are stacked to be overlapping instead of the other single bars being the same as before.

Please prepare some test data also.

Have a play with this spec in vega editor:. Adjust the width and offset until you are happy with the final result. I couldn't get this to work until I noticed the spelling of "PlusQuatation".

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Date": "2024-05-05",
        "PlusQuatation": 47515794,
        "Actual": 57515794,
        "Expected": 77515794
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-06-05",
        "PlusQuatation": 37515794,
        "Actual": 27515794,
        "Expected": 47515794
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-07-05",
        "PlusQuatation": 27515794,
        "Actual": 67515794,
        "Expected": 47515794
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-08-05",
        "PlusQuatation": 57515794,
        "Actual": 17515794,
        "Expected": 27515794
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-09-05",
        "PlusQuatation": 67515794,
        "Actual": 77515794,
        "Expected": 87515794
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-10-05",
        "PlusQuatation": 27515794,
        "Actual": 67515794,
        "Expected": 47515794
      }
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "timeUnit": "month",
      "title": "Month",
      "axis": {"format": "%b"},
      "scale": {"padding": 0.3}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": "green",
        "xOffset": -25,
        "width": 50,
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {"value": 0.7},
        "y": {"field": "PlusQuatation", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": "orange",
        "xOffset": 25,
        "width": 50,
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {"value": 0.7},
        "y": {"field": "Expected", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": "blue",
        "xOffset": 0,
        "width": 50,
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {"value": 0.7},
        "y": {"field": "Actual", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Values"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "title": "Actual, Expected, and PlusQuatation over Time",
  "config": {
    "axis": {"titleFontSize": 12, "labelFontSize": 10},
    "legend": {"orient": "bottom", "labelFontSize": 10}
  },
  "width": 800
}

